# C# Difference between "using anything" and "system.anything"

Tags: c#, using

Is there any difference between doing this...

```
    using System.Xml.Linq; 
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(page);
```

or this...

```
    System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(page);
```

Other than the first one makes everything easier to write and cleaner code?

edit: I only used Linq as an example, I'm asking this for everything using/system/etc.. related.

Comment: That the first one is legal while the second one is illegal? A good second one would be System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xml = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(page); (this unless you defined an XDocument static class in a namespace the code has access to that implements Parse, or you have a field/property named XDocument.... or some other cases that surely exist and that we will ignore)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference in terms of emitted IL. But in the second case you are writing more code which IMHO is not necessary especially when you want to declare multiple `XDocument` instances in the same class. It's simply useless to be that much explicit when declaring a variable type. Actually an even shorter way would be:

```
using System.Xml.Linq; 
...

var xml = XDocument.Parse(page);
```

It's even easier with <kbd>Shift+Alt+F10+Enter</kbd> because in this case you only write:

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(page);
```

and Visual Studio automatically adds the proper `using` after putting the cursor over `XDocument`.

Comment: unless you need to explicitly identify a class as you have two types with the same name in different namespaces.

Comment: @Femaref, this would be true if both classes must be used at the same time. If not, adding a `using` directive to the proper namespace would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

It's normally okay to just use the "using" method.  However, you may have to explicitly qualify a namespace inline if there are namespace conflicts (for example, if you had your own class called `XDocument` in your namespace)